# Get the output label of calender toplevel from the master window having "Select Date" button, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, calendar, widget, toplevel

I have a doubt, how to get the top-level value in the master window's label. I mean like i couldn't return the entered value from toplevel window to main's self.
I tried other ways and it didn't work

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
  
class Application(tk.Frame):
    
    def _init_(self,master):
        Frame._init_(self,master)
        self.master=master
        self.label=Label(text="",font=("Georgia,12"))
        self.label.place(x=50,y=80)
        self.create_widgets() 
    

def calendar_view():
    def print_sel():
        return cal.get()
        
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
        
    cal = Calendar(top,
                   font="Arial 14",selectmode='day',
                    cursor="hand1", year=2020)         
    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    ttk.Button(top, text="ok", command=print_sel).pack()                   
root=tk.Tk()

s = ttk.Style(root)
s.theme_use('clam')
root.title("Date")
root.geometry("800x500")

button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Test Start Date', bg='#0073BD',height=1,width=15,padx=5,pady=2, fg="white",command=calendar_view)
button.place(x=500,y=100)
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="<-Click to select Test Start Date", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#e6e9f2", font=("calibri",8))
label1.place(x=630,y=100)

button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Test End Date', bg='#0073BD',height=1,width=15,padx=5,pady=2,fg="white",command=calendar_view)
button.place(x=500,y=150)
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="<-Click to select Test End Date", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#e6e9f2", font=("calibri",8))
label1.place(x=630,y=150)

app=Application(root)
root.configure(bg='#e6e9f2')
root.mainloop()
```

[[here is the reference of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ytL.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ytL.png)

Comment: Have you tried using `global`?

Comment: Why don't you use `DateEntry` instead?

Comment: Yes i can do it, but i wish to try it and my frnd wish it to be like that and we are trying to make it more presentable @acw1668

Comment: I havent tried ```global``` and what is it @CoolCloud

Comment: Inside `print_sel()` assign, a variable to `cal.selection_get()` and then say `global that_variable_name` inside on top of function.

Comment: Thanks @CoolCloud

Comment: How do you know that you are selecting *"start date"* or *"end date"* if using same global variable?

Comment: well i created duplicate global variable @acw1668

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@acw1668 Here is the updated code, can you send me your version updated code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
  
class Application(tk.Frame):
    
    def _init_(self,master):
        Frame._init_(self,master)
        self.master=master
        self.label=Label(text="",font=("Georgia,12"))
        self.label.place(x=50,y=80)
        self.create_widgets() 
    
caldate1 = " "
caldate2 = " "
    
def calendar_view1():
    def print_sel1():
        global caldate1
        caldate1 = cal1.selection_get()
        label1.config(text = caldate1)
        return caldate1
    
    top1 = tk.Toplevel(root)
    cal1 = Calendar(top1,
                   font="Arial 14",selectmode='day',
                    cursor="hand2", year=2020)         
    cal1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    ttk.Button(top1, text="ok", command=print_sel1).pack()  
    
def calendar_view2():
    def print_sel2():
        global caldate2
        caldate2 = cal2.selection_get()
        label2.config(text = caldate2)
        return caldate2
    
    top2 = tk.Toplevel(root)
    cal2 = Calendar(top2,
                   font="Arial 14",selectmode='day',
                    cursor="hand2", year=2020)         
    cal2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    ttk.Button(top2, text="ok", command=print_sel2).pack()

    
root=tk.Tk()

s = ttk.Style(root)
s.theme_use('clam')
root.title("Date")
root.geometry("800x500")

button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Test Start Date', bg='#0073BD',height=1,width=15,padx=5,pady=2, fg="white",command=calendar_view1)
button.place(x=500,y=100)
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="<-Click to select Test Start Date", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#e6e9f2", font=("calibri",8))
label1.place(x=630,y=100)

button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Test End Date', bg='#0073BD',height=1,width=15,padx=5,pady=2,fg="white",command=calendar_view2)
button.place(x=500,y=150)
label2 = tk.Label(root, text="<-Click to select Test End Date", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#e6e9f2", font=("calibri",8))
label2.place(x=630,y=150)

app=Application(root)
root.configure(bg='#e6e9f2')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use two `StringVar` to store the start date and end date, and pass the variable to `calendar_view()`:

```py
def calendar_view(var):
    def print_sel():
        # update the var
        var.set(cal.get_date())
        # close the calendar window
        top.destroy()
        
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    cal = Calendar(top, font="Arial 14",selectmode='day',
                    cursor="hand1", year=2020, date_pattern='y-mm-dd')         
    cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    ttk.Button(top, text="ok", command=print_sel).pack()
    # make window a modal window
    top.grab_set()
    top.wait_window(top)
```

Then update the creation of the two buttons:

```py
button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Test Start Date', bg='#0073BD',height=1,width=15,padx=5,pady=2, fg="white",
                   command=lambda: calendar_view(startdate))

button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Test End Date', bg='#0073BD',height=1,width=15,padx=5,pady=2,fg="white",
                   command=lambda: calendar_view(enddate))
```

and associate the two variables to the two labels, so that their text are updated whenever the variables are updated:

```py
startdate = tk.StringVar(value="<-Click to select Test Start Date")
label1 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=startdate, padx=10, pady=10, bg="#e6e9f2", font=("calibri",8))

enddate = tk.StringVar(value="<-Click to select Test End Date")
label2 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=enddate, padx=10, pady=10, bg="#e6e9f2", font=("calibri",8))
```

Comment: But i got the blank window

Comment: Better post your updated code since it works to me.